# Does D-link DWA-548 Support 5Ghz band?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm buying a new modem and It supports 5Ghz band but I don't know whether my wi-fi pci-e card supports this function.

I've looked around internet and DWA-548's Manual but It's not mentioned anywhere whether It supports 5Ghz band or not. DWA-548 supports 802.11n. Does that mean it supports 5Ghz band as well??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the [datasheet](ftp://ftp.dlink.ca/PRODUCTS/DWA-548/DWA-548_DATASHEET_1.00_EN.PDF) for your DWA-548 device. There is a chart on this page that shows your card is classed as `N300` and not `N300 dual band`. As such, your card only supports the 2.4GHz band.

Please note that being Wireless N does *not* mean it will definitely support the 5GHz band.

You could try [these instructions](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/how-enable-5ghz-on-your-laptop-3608743/) which may reveal more information on what your current driver supports (near the bottom of the page). I am confident this will confirm your card only supports 2.4GHz though.

> How to find out if your laptop supports 5GHz
>
> Unfortunately there's no
> easy way to get this information. The best way is to open Control
> Panel, go to Device Manager and find the make and model of your
> laptop's Wi-Fi under the Network adapters section.
>
> ...
> You can also right-click on the adaptor in Device Manager, click Properties and then switch to the Advanced tab. You'll see a list of properties, one of which should mention 5GHz. If you don't see an option to enable or disable 5GHz, either your adapter doesn't support it, or the wrong drivers are installed.

Comment: Under the features tab, this device is listed as single band. http://us.dlink.com/products/connect/wireless-n300-pci-express-desktop-adapter/